# Implications of Intl.Collator sensitivity:'base' in languages other than English

Tags: javascript, internationalization, locale

I'd like to do a client-side, case-insensitive [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) of strings.

I can use:

```js
a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { sensitivity: 'base', numeric: 'true' })
```

or, alternatively, with [Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator):

```js
Intl.Collator(undefined, { sensitivity: 'base', numeric: 'true' }).compare(a,b)
```

I know this will work perfectly in English. However, my question is whether there are any locales where `sensitivity: 'base'` would lead to a sort order that people of that locale would consider confusing or strange?

If, instead, I first mapped the strings to `toLocaleLowerCase()`, and then sorted without `sensitivity: 'base'` specified as an option, would that produce an identical sort order in all locales?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#using_options)? Swedish and German are listed as common examples where this makes a difference.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks - yes - I read that documentation. However, for example, since I don't speak German, I can't tell if people would find it confusing or strange if a list of words beginning with `ä` were mixed in with a list of words beginning with `a`. I'm not sure if `sensitivity: 'base'` for the German locale will imply that it would not be strange to see them mixed together. Perhaps `sensitivity: 'base'` means the order you'd expect to see words listed in a dictionary, tailored for each locale. It doesn't explicitly state that in the docs.

Comment: In German, `a` and `ä` are sorted equivalently. It’s [_Swedish_](//developer.mozilla.org/en/search?q=swedish) where the distinction between `a` and `ä` applies, so `sensitivity: "base"` would be incorrect there.

Comment: @SebastianSimon but, if the locale is Swedish, the docs you linked to says that there will be a distinction between them when sensitivity: "base" is specified, so that would work perfectly, right? If sensitivity: "base" means dictionary order in every locale, that would be wonderful.